# php unset session cart array

Tags: php, arrays, session

```
    Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
         [subject] => Computer [price] => 33.00
         [quantity] => 1 
         [total] => 33
         [level] => Array (
            [CSA] => 1
            [CSB] => 2
         )
      )
   )
   [1] => Array (
      [0] => Array (
         [subject] => English
         [price] => 33.00
         [quantity] => 25
         [total] => 825
         [level] => Array (
            [Eintro] => 1
            [EA] =>
            [EB] => 1
         )
      )
   )
```

I have a session cart array as mentioned above. How to remove the item related to 'Computer' i.e. if the subject Computer and price, quantity, total and level which is related to the subject Computer.

I know I have to use unset SESSION. But how to unset the session array only for the Computer row so that it doesn't affect other items array in the cart?

```
var_export($session_cart);

array ( 
   0 => array ( 
      0 => array ( 
         'subject' => 'Computer', 
         'price' => '33.00',
         'quantity' => 1,
         'total' => 33, 
         'level' => array ( 
            'CSA' => '1', 
            'CSB' => '2',
         ),
      ),
   ), 
   1 => array ( 
      0 => array ( 
         'subject' => 'English',
         'price' => '33.00',
         'quantity' => 25,
         'total' => 825,
         'level' => array (
            'EA' => '1',
            'EB' => '1',
         ), 
      ), 
   ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You should loop through your cart session:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['cart']); $i++)
{
   if($_SESSION['cart'][$i]['subject'] == 'computer')
   {
      unset($_SESSION['cart'][$i]);
   }
}
```

Note that I assume you have put all of your cart's items and values in a single `$_SESSION['cart']`. If not, then remove cart and use `$_SESSION[$i]` (which seems strange though).

Comment: it works. I had the same problem before (when newbie) and solved it. Just put the php code when you assign $_SESSION a new cart item. this would help much

Comment: a `)` was missing for the `count()` function, it should correctly work now.

Comment: Also, take a look at `array_search()` that could help you doing something faster. http://fr2.php.net/array_search

Answer (score 0):

When you are removing item call `removeItem()` with array and item to be deleted it will return modified array.

try like this:

```
  function removeItem($arr,$item) {
   for($i=0;$i < count($arr);$i++){
    foreach($arr[$i] as $b){
     if(in_array($item,$b)){
      unset($arr[$i]);
     }
    }
    }
    return $arr;
   }
   $arr =  removeItem($arr,"English");
   print_r($arr);
   $_SESSION['cart'] =  $arr;
```

Output: 
When i have pass english as `$item` the output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [subject] => Computer
                    [price] => 33.00
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [total] => 33
                    [level] => Array
                        (
                            [CSA] => 1
                            [CSB] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

[demo](https://eval.in/107822)

Comment: This will remove the item once only, if I add computer back to the cart it won't remove it already

Comment: Still, it will only remove the first item in the cart. And how do I update the value to my $_SESSION['cart']?

Comment: Still, it only remove the first item even I pass it English to the function

Comment: did you check the demo link? i have passed english and it deleted english. there is no way it delete computer if you pass english

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that can search in a multi array and execute a callback function if the value is found :

```
    function extend_array_search($needle,&$haystack,$callback = '') {
    $array_res = array();
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        $res = null;
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $res = extend_array_search($needle,$value);
        } else {
            if($value == $needle) {
                $res = $key;
            } 
        }
        if($res != null) $array_res[$key] = $res;

    }
    if(!empty($callback)) {
        $array_res = $callback($array_res,&$haystack);
    }
    if($array_res != null) {
        return $array_res;
    }
}

function unset_array_key($key_to_unset, $array_to_modify) {
    if(is_array($key_to_unset)) {
        foreach ($key_to_unset as $key => $value) {
            unset($array_to_modify[$key]);
        }
    } else {
        unset($array_to_modify[$key_to_unset]);
    }
}



extend_array_search('Computer',$session_cart) // return the keys containing computer OR
 extend_array_search('Computer', $session_cart,'unset_array_key'); // unset the value in $session_cart
```